# Apache Rewrite Breaks PHP SuperGlobals

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a quite odd mystery. I have a rather simple Apache Rewrite and for some odd reason it is messing up my php Superglobals. First off the Rewrite is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

When this rule is in place the only Superglobals that are $_GET and $_REQUEST (of course $REQUEST does because it gets them from $_GET, ...). No matter what I put in the URL I only ever receive /index_php as the only key and it has no value. At first I thought I had messed something up in my code but as the first line of the index file I tried the following:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key = $value<br/>";
}
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key = $value<br/>";
}
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    echo "$key = $value<br/>";
}
```

The only thing printed is "/index_php = " twice. I've messed with a couple rewrites before but clearly I'm doing something incorrect. As a side note this is my expected behavior:

```
URL: localhost/users/dashboard?item=id
```

Which would give me the $_GET superglobal with key: item, value: id. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the original query string in your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
                                    ^^^
```

That way, regardless of the new values that you might add in the future, the old ones will get passed as well.